# Completely Shut Down Java Application

Tags: java

In my standalone GUI application, I will install a Windows Closed handle on the application

formWindowClosed

within the closed handle, I will perform necessary clean up, and did a final System.exit(0) at the every last code.

This works well, until I receive a complain from customer that the program is not able to shut down properly. My suspect is that, there are still pending I/O operation, which cannot even be interrupted by System.exit(0).

I wish to use Process.destroy() too, to give a final HIT to the application.

However, I am not sure how I can obtain current running process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258099/how-to-close-a-java-swing-application-from-the-code) on SO.