# How to close a Frame by clickin on the top right "x"?

Tags: java, awt, frame

Got a Frame in Java:

```
 Frame AFrame = new Frame("Frame with components");
```

The frame's top right "x" close button is not working by default.
How can I set that ?

Comment: You really should be using Swing components, not AWT components. That being said, replace `Frame` with `JFrame`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and then

```
JFrame AFrame = new JFrame("Frame with components");
AFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

But if you insist on Frame then add a listener:

```
AFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Agreed, the OP should probably be using a `JFrame`, just for reference, here's how to close an AWT frame: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/frame_CloseHide.html

Comment: `System.exit(0)` may be a bit overkill: perhaps `AFrame.this.dispose()` is a better option. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258099/how-to-close-a-java-swing-application-from-the-code

Comment: @BartKiers thanks, I didn't know it. You learn a new thing everyday.

Comment: `rame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISOPSE_ON_CLOSE);`