# Project won't stop running on NetBeans

Tags: java

I started writing a small program to learn a bit more about java and try to design my layouts by hand without always using NetBeans.

Thing is, when I run my project and close it, it won't stop running in NetBeans, so everytime I re-run it creates another run. By searching and looking at another GUI I had created using NetBeans I thought adding the

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

would do the trick, but I guess I am wrong.

Can someone please explain me what I should do?

Here is a SSCCE of my programa: http://pastebin.com/QhKpwdDw

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this question: [How to close a Java Swing application from the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258099/how-to-close-a-java-swing-application-from-the-code), as it deals with closing the application in general and also how to ensure it completely terminated.

But to answer your question quickly, there are a couple of options.

### Option 1

Since you are extending `JFrame` in your class, you can just use [`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) to quit.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

**NOTE:** `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` exits all `JFrames` in your application, not just the one it is applied to.

### Option 2

This is most likely not the answer you want, but [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) will close only the `JFrame` you are applying it to.

If you have multiple `JFrames` open, or if you have any other `Threads`, they will keep running and the program will not end. But if you only have one `Thread` and one `JFrame`, this will close the application.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

### My Preference

I would go with Option 1, disagreeing with everyone else. It is directly tied to `JFrame` and not dependent on `WindowConstants`, which makes things cleaner and more reliable. But more importantly, it closes *all* of the windows, not just the one that you apply it to.

Even though it looks like you only have one window, you may have other internal `Threads` elsewhere in your program that NetBeans is throwing in there.

To be sure everything closes, you want to use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

### Extra Information

For a discussion on how `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` differ: http://www.coderanch.com/t/340183/GUI/java/DISPOSE-CLOSE-vs-EXIT-CLOSE

Documentation on `JFrame's` `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Documentation on `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and other `WindowConstants`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

Comment: public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

I was missing the "frame.set..."! All works now! But thank you on your answer, will take some time to further read on those topics!

Answer (score 1):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

public static final int DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
The dispose-window default window close operation.
Note: When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate. See AWT Threading Issues for more information.

See Also:
Window.dispose(), JInternalFrame.dispose(), Constant Field Values

Comment: I tried it, but the same happens! I will read further on those subjects!

Comment: `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will not terminate the program if other `Threads` or `JFrames` are open. It will only close the frame it is applied to.

Comment: public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

I was missing the "frame.set..."! All works now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Place it **inside the constructor of your JFrame** or **the class which extends JFrame**

`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra there is no need for the `JFrame.` in the parameter, as the class extends `JFrame` already.

Comment: public JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

I was missing the "frame.set..."! All works now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here ([setDefaultCloseOperation doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)) you can use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE if you want to trigger a window listener (for example to close a database connection).
In such a case it make sense to choose DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE instead of EXIT_ON_CLOSE.

PS : Don't forget although to add a `System.exit(0)` at the end of the window listener code, so that the application exits.