# Change Button to JButton can't fixe it(((

Tags: java, image, swing, button, jbutton

I'm stuck using Button and JButton

expected result.. ( all information working )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qX7v.png
 and what I have 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gao.png

I want to replace this:

```
Button butRock = new Button("Rock");
butRock.addActionListener(this);
ButtPan.add(butRock);
```

To This:

```
BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("rock.jpg"));
JButton butRock = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
butRock.addActionListener(this);
ButtPan.add(butRock);
```

I'm stuck because when I replace Button to JButton the program doesn't work properly...when I use this JButton
Question: How to replace the button with picture and that program still work properly...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
public class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public JLabel JWoL,JWoLPlayer,JWoLPC,JNumWin,JNumLose,JNumTie, logo;
    public JLabel JWinT,JLoseT,JTieT, rpsP, rpsC, result;
    JPanel LabelsPan;
    static final int WINS = 0, LOSSES = 1, DRAWS = 2;
    int[] counts = new int[3];
    String[] strings = {"| You Win", "| You Lose", "| Draw"};
    JLabel[] labels = {JNumWin, JNumLose, JNumTie};


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        gui theWindow = new gui();
        theWindow.show();
    }

    private void record(int type)
    {
        JWoL.setText(strings[type]);
        counts[type]++;
        labels[type].setText(""+counts[type]);
    }

    public gui() throws IOException
    {
        JPanel logo = new JPanel();
        logo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("logo.jpg"));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
        add(picLabel);


        JPanel ButtPan=new JPanel();
        ButtPan.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));


        BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("rock.jpg"));
        JButton butRock = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
        butRock.addActionListener(this);
        ButtPan.add(butRock);

        Button butPaper = new Button("Paper");
        butPaper.addActionListener(this);
        ButtPan.add(butPaper);

        Button butScissors = new Button("Scissors");
        butScissors.addActionListener(this);
        ButtPan.add(butScissors);


        JWoLPlayer = new JLabel();
        JWoLPC = new JLabel();
        JWoL= new JLabel();


        JLabel rpsPlayer= new JLabel("| Your Choice:  ");
        JLabel rpsComputer= new JLabel("| Computers Choice:  ");
        setTitle("| RoPaS GAME |");


        LabelsPan=new JPanel();
        LabelsPan.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

        rpsP = new JLabel();
        LabelsPan.add(rpsPlayer);
        LabelsPan.add(JWoLPlayer);

        rpsC = new JLabel();
        LabelsPan.add(rpsComputer);
        LabelsPan.add(JWoLPC);

        result =new JLabel();
        LabelsPan.add(JWoL,"Center");


        JPanel WLPan = new JPanel();
        WLPan.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));


        JWinT = new JLabel("Wins: ");
        JLoseT = new JLabel("Losses: ");
        JTieT = new JLabel("Ties: ");

        WLPan.add(JWinT);
        JNumWin = new JLabel();
        WLPan.add(JNumWin);
        WLPan.add(JLoseT);

        JNumLose = new JLabel();
        WLPan.add(JNumLose);
        WLPan.add(JTieT);

        JNumTie = new JLabel();
        WLPan.add(JNumTie);
        JLabel[] labels1 = {JNumWin, JNumLose, JNumTie};
        labels = labels1;


        JPanel TwoPanesN1=new JPanel();

        TwoPanesN1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TwoPanesN1.add(logo,"North");
        TwoPanesN1.add(LabelsPan,"West");
        TwoPanesN1.add(WLPan,"East");

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        getContentPane().add(ButtPan);
        getContentPane().add(TwoPanesN1);


        Font fontDisplay = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
        JWoL.setFont(fontDisplay);
        LabelsPan.setFont(fontDisplay);
        setSize(400,250);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev){System.exit(0);}});
    }



    public void Play(String PlayerChoice)
    {
        String PCchoice=PCansw();
        JWoLPC.setText(PCchoice);

        if(PlayerChoice.equals(PCchoice))
            record(DRAWS);


        else if(PlayerChoice.equals("Rock"))
            if(PCchoice.equals("Paper"))
                record(LOSSES);
            else
                record(WINS);


        else if(PlayerChoice.equals("Paper"))
            if(PCchoice.equals("Scissors"))
                record(LOSSES);
            else
                record(WINS);


        else if(PlayerChoice.equals("Scissors"))
            if(PCchoice.equals("Rock"))
                record(LOSSES);
            else
                record(WINS);

    }



    public String PCansw()
    {
        String rpsPC2="";
        int rpsPC=(int)(Math.random( )*3)+1;
        if(rpsPC==1)
            rpsPC2= "Rock";
        else if(rpsPC==2)
            rpsPC2= "Paper";
        else if(rpsPC==3)
            rpsPC2= "Scissors";
        return rpsPC2;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit"))
            System.exit(0);
        else
        {
            JWoLPlayer.setText(e.getActionCommand());
            Play(e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: *What exactly* doesn't work properly? What is supposed to happen; what is happening instead? Also, please reduce your code sample to the minimum required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: when I replace button with Jbutton the actual code doesn't work, I mean the the random numbers that have to show up not working and the counting not working

Comment: could you elaborate on the actual problem in terms of error messages, exceptions, compiler warnings, expected result vs. actual result, etc, etc?

Comment: expected result.. ( all information working )
http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qX7v.png and what I have http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gao.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `getActionCommand` to determine which `JButton` was clicked but this property is not set by default in Swing. You would have to call

```
butRock.setActionCommand("Rock");
```

`java.awt.Button` automatically uses the label property as the `ActionCommand` if it not explicitly set. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#getActionCommand%28%29)

> If the command name is null (default) then this method returns the label of the button.

---

*Some asides:*

- Better to avoid [mixing heavy & lightweight components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) and use lightweight components throughout the application.
- As your *Rock*, *Paper*, *Scissors* buttons have identical functionality, consider using an [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).
- A direct instance `JFrame` is typically used rather than extending the class
- Use [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- [Window#show](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show%28%29) is *deprecated*. Use `Window#setVisible`.
- Don't use `System.exit` - See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258099/how-to-close-a-java-swing-application-from-the-code)