# Why won't this application terminate with DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE?

Tags: java, swing

I read that DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE should be used instead of EXIT_ON_CLOSE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/259283/3547126) and got confused. Does `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` terminate the application if it has no other active threads/frames?
I landed on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe) that had [a link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) to an article that states:

> DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE – Automatically hide and dispose the frame. When this is the only frame in the application the VM will also be terminated.

If my assumption that an application does terminate when it uses `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` as its value for `setDefaultCloseOperation()` is correct, why won't the following application terminate when I click the exit button?

Code:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              new Test();
          }
      });
  }

  public Test() {
      super();
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**Update:**
I am currently running Mac OS Yosemite, and `java -version` outputs:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

I ran the program on my usual IDE (Eclipse) and on the command line, but both keep the JVM running after I close the JFrame.

Comment: *"Does setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) terminate the application if it has no other active threads/frames?"* - Yes, which is a good way to test if there are any rouge (non-daemon) threads

Comment: What's happening? Is it an exception, or does nothing happen? Does the frame actually close?

Comment: Also, your test code works fine for me (the JVM terminates after the frame is closed)

Comment: No exception. The JFrame closes, but the application does not terminate.

Comment: And your code works fine for me with the JVM exiting as expected.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS (Yosemite). Is there anyway this could be a JVM issue?

Comment: Which VM are you using?

Comment: @VinceEmigh, what do you mean? I use the standard Java VM for Mac OS X.

Comment: For all we know, you could be using an implementation other than HotSpot. Which version of HotSpot are you using? Looking for possible bug reports would be easier if we knew the version. Are you using the most recent version?

Comment: Also verified expected JVM termination after pressing the "x" button to close the frame.  I'm on OS X Yosemite, using HotSpot JVM (1.7.0_75).  Are you running from the command line or an IDE?

Comment: Edited the question to include `java -version` output. @blazetopher, I tried both options and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @Aprendiz do you test it with the code you posted, or do you test it with another, more complex application, that could start additional threads?

Comment: @JBNizet I am testing with the code I posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM actually terminates. What happens is while the JVM exits immediately when using `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, it takes up to 15 or more seconds to terminate (on my machine) when I use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.
I wrongfully assumed that the JVM would terminate immediately like in the first scenario, but apparently that's not the case. The minimum amount of time I had to wait was 2 seconds, but it normally takes over 5 seconds, which continuously led me to believe that it would not terminate, and I would forcefully terminate the JVM myself every time.
To me this behavior feels like its not normal, but I suppose that it would be completely transparent to a end-user, since the `JFrame` closes as soon as the exit button is clicked.

I have no explanation as to why using these values for `setDefaultCloseOperation()` is different for the JVM in such a minimal example.